# Why do I get error 400 on http request when sending datas to API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

Good morning everyone,

I have been struggling with a 400 error in my JS code.

API need to get contact object with all information from the form, and an array of products id to return an order number.

So I get all the values from the form and put them into the contact object. Then i need to get the products in the cart from a localstorage, get the id of all the objects inside the cart, put them into a products array to send to the API.

```js
// Création de l'objet contact à l'envoi du formulaire
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  let contact = {
    nom: document.querySelector("#nom").value,
    prenom: document.querySelector("#prenom").value,
    adresse: document.querySelector("#adresse").value,
    ville: document.querySelector("#ville").value,
    email: document.querySelector("#email").value
  }
  //Création du tableau de produits
  let panier = localStorage.getItem("panier");
  panier = JSON.parse(panier);
  let products = [];
  panier.produits.forEach(element => {
    products.push(element._id);
  })
  console.log(products);

  //Envoi des données à l'API
  let requete = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/cameras/order';
  requete.open("POST", url);
  requete.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  requete.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(requete.responseText);
  })

  let envoi = JSON.stringify({contact,products});
  requete.send(envoi);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <p>
      <label for="Nom"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Nom" value="Nom" id="nom" required>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="Prénom"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Prénom" value="Prénom" id="prenom" required>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="Adresse"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Adresse" value="Adresse" id="adresse" required>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="Ville"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Ville" value="Ville" id="ville" required>
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="Email"></label>
      <input type="email" name="Email" value="Email" id="email" required>
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Commander">
      </p>
    </form>
    <script src="commande.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

URL is correct for sure, and I really don't understand what i did wrong on this request.

Thank you for your help

Have a nice day and a nice week-end

Comment: 400 means bad request. You need to check what is expected by the API. It could be the expected number of parameters or parameter values are not passed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The API needs contact object and array with products id to work ...

Comment: As per the explanation the code seems to be correct and only way to figure this out is your server side log. Does the server send any more information apart from 400?

Comment: @Mikev60 400 bad request means the server is not able to accept that request, even though you might think the payload is valid. Can you try to print the response of xmlhttprequest using: ```requete.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (requete.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(requete.responseText);
    }
}``` Can you provide the backend API code?